# Understanding a piece of a Rail code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

The example URL for a service my client should call look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/providers/?query=eric&group_ids[]=1F23&group_ids[]=423&start=3&limit=20
```

The helper module/method that is already writtne is like this, that I should utilize for my own client:

```
def create_http_request(method, path, options = {})
  # create/configure http
  http = Net::HTTP.new(@base_uri.host, @base_uri.port)
  http.open_timeout = options[:open_timeout] || @open_timeout
  http.read_timeout = options[:read_timeout] || @read_timeout

  # create/configure request
  if method == :get
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path)
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "Error: invalid http method: #{method}"
  end

  return http, request
end
```

In other parts of the similar code that others have written I see something like this: In order to call that create_http_request method:

```
 def person_search(query, options = {})
  params = {
    query: query,
      group_ids: options[:group_ids],
    start: options[:page] || @default_page,
    limit: options[:page_size] || @default_page_size
  }

  pathSemantic = "/patients/?#{ params.to_param }"
  httpSemantic, requestSemantic = create_http_request(:get, pathSemantic, options)
```

So mainly I don't understand what is she doing with params , why do we need to do that? Is that the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about the to_param method? It creates a param string that can be used in the URL. You can read about it here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

So, in the person search method, the parameters are constructed based on the query, the values given in the options hash and the default options stored in the object. They are attached to the path to create the pathSemantic string, which is then passed to the create_http_request method.

Re. the construction of the parameters -- it is a hash with the query parameter mapped to the :query key, the value of the option :group_id in mapped to the :group_id key, the value of the option :page mapped to :start, etc.

```
  params = {                                         # params is a hash
    query: query,                                    # the key query is mapped to the query method parameter (we got it from the call to the method)
    group_ids: options[:group_ids],                  # the key :group_ids is mapped to the value that we got in the options hash under the :group_id key (we also got the options as a parameter in teh call to the method)
    start: options[:page] || @default_page,          # the key :start is mapped to the value that we got in the options hash under the :page key. In case it is not set, we'll use the value in the instance variable @default_page
    limit: options[:page_size] || @default_page_size # the key :page_size is mapped to the value that we got in the options hash under the :page_size key. In case it is not set, we'll use the value in the instance variable @default_page_size
  }
```

If you wonder about the x || y notation -- all it means is that in case x is not set, the value from y will be used (this is the shortcut operator 'or' used in an idiomatic form)

The way to_param works on a key mapped to an array:

```
{group_ids: ["asdf","dfgf","ert"]}.to_param
=> "group_ids%5B%5D=asdf&group_ids%5B%5D=dfgf&group_ids%5B%5D=ert"
```

which is URL encoding for

```
"group_ids[]=asdf&group_ids[]=dfgf&group_ids[]=ert"
```

Comment: well mostly the whole params part .. that says  params = {
    query: query, etc...

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer but have a last question: notice in the URL service that I posted ( that example.com ) the query can have more than one group_ids[] ... so the way she has done it in that method can still work for me too ?

Comment: It should. I tried in rails console: and got this: {group_ids: ["asdf","dfgf","ert"]}.to_param
=> "group_ids%5B%5D=asdf&group_ids%5B%5D=dfgf&group_ids%5B%5D=ert"  which is URL encoding for "group_ids[]=asdf&group_ids[]=dfgf&group_ids[]=ert"

Comment: hmm in similar codes I saw something like this too: Addressable::Template.new .... I think that's another way of doing the same thing but with this Addressable gem